# Chosen not working inside the form using jquery-steps

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen, jquery-steps

Chosen (chosen.jquery.js) is not working inside the form, after applying jquery-steps. If that code runs outside the form that is used for jquery-steps, it works perfectly fine. I am also having the same problem with `datePicker` inside the jquery-steps. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Can you show us some relevant code?

Answer (score 17):

You need to initialize jquery steps first and then other plugin initialization
    http://jsfiddle.net/6YkZV/50/

```
$(function () {
//step1
 $("#wizard").steps({
    bodyTag: "fieldset",
    headerTag: "h4"
  });
//step2
 $(".datepicker").datepicker();
});
```